# WEB приложение на Spring Boot

Tags: spring

начал изучать Spring Boot и хочу попробовать небольшое веб-приложение. Наткнулся на множество примеров где на Spring Boot пишется REST API, а вывода информации во фронт используют JS или другой фреймворк... Я так понимаю это проще и удобнее, написал одни раз api и использовал для веб-приложений, для мобильных и и.д. В общем хотел бы узнать как вообще пишут сейчас, что используют для backend что для fronta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, это один из примеров работы приложения. Есть так же приложения, которые вычитывают из брокера сообщений и что-то с данными делают (сохраняют в БД, общаются с другими, если речь идет про микроархитектурную разработку и т.д.). А фронт используют в примерах в основном для того, чтобы проще воспринимать пример, чтобы не пользоваться курлом или постманом.

Есть приложения, которые занимаются просто обработкой информации.

На фронте в данный момент пользуется спросом React/Angular/Vue, насколько мне известно.

Но как показывает опыт очень сложно делать и фронт и бэк. Лучше выбрать что-то одно и развиваться в этом направлении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.. Меня собственно интересует следующая тематика.. Есть медицинская информационная система у нас в учреждении. Модуль регистрации пациентов, модуль работы врачей и т.д.. Хочу реализовать в качестве проекта для портфолио какие-то функции из него в виде веб-приложения.. Например регистрацию пациентов, добавление каких-то справочников.. Т.к. я для себя изучаю хочется понять и бэк и фронт.. с бэк понятно более менее - хочу на spring boot делать, а вот с фронтом пока не знаю, начал изучать на чем вообще пишут, смотрю везде angular, react это все основано на javascript я так понимаю.

Comment: @Kolhoznik По поводу фронта мало что скажу, но по поводу бэка скажу так. Если есть модули, то лучшее - микросервисная архитектура